# MonoTouch/Xamarin vs Titanium

Tags: xamarin.ios, titanium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monotouch or Titanium for rapid application development on IPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488402/monotouch-or-titanium-for-rapid-application-development-on-iphone)

I have an idea for a mobile app, which I would like to create for both IPhones, Android and Windows Phones, and I was thinking about using either MonoTouch/Xamarin or Titanium to develop it.

I come from a webdeveloper background so if it doesn't matter if it is Javascript/html or C#. Has any of you tried both frameworks, and can give a few pros and cons of both frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a usefull information on this topic [Titanium Appcelerator Vs. MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663870/appcelerator-vs-monotouch-which-one-is-best-for-a-net-developer)

Comment: Thanks, I have seen the thread, but it discusses MonoTouch vs Native and not so much MonoTouch/Xamarin vs. Titanium.

Comment: This is set to be the answer, in lack of better answers.

Comment: I've created an open source project http://propertycross.com that helps select a cross-platform mobile framework by showing the same application implemented with Sencha, Titanium, Xamarin and more ...