# Best Framework for native apps

Tags: mobile, titanium, xamarin, native, tablet

I want to develope a native app (for Android and IOS, later Windows Phones, too. It will be designed for tablet computers like IPad etc.). It is an Enterprise application connecting to the database. 
What is very important to me, is:

1. User Experience: It has to have this native Look-In and must be really attractive.
2. Performance: It has to have a high performance. 
   So with regard to the points I mentioned, I am looking for a framework offering the best components and controls for native development. Of course, it would be desirable to use an cross platform framework but for native apps.
   I tried out Xamarin and read a bit about Appcelerator Titanium. 
   So referring to the criteria I mentioned, what is the best framework to develop my app?

Comment: SO is generally not the best place to ask opinion / personal preference questions like this. I would try [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead. However, this specific question has been asked before: [I prefer this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1515490/874257)

Comment: If I had 20 Reputations then I would go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would go for Xamarin. It's based on the mono project which is now quite mature. Xamarin have recently partnered with companies such as Microsoft and SAP.

I've generally found the troubleshooting to coding ratio higher for titanium than Xamarin. In my opinion Xamarin is the stronger platform; albeit a commercial product.